# phone number validation in android is not working please help me

Tags: android

```
private boolean validate(){

        String MobilePattern = "[0-9]{10}";
        //String email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
         if(name.length() > 25){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pls enter less the 25 characher in user name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
else if (number.getText().toString().matches(MobilePattern))
        {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "phone number is valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
        /*else if(!number.getText().toString().matches(MobilePattern))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid 10 digit phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return false;
        }*/
        else if(name.length() == 0 || number.length() == 0 || email.length() == 0 || subject.length() == 0 || message.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pls fill the empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        else if (email.getText().toString().matches(emailPattern))
        { 
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return true;
        }
        else if (!email.getText().toString().matches(emailPattern))
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter Valid Email Adress",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: I don't see a question in here. In what way is it not working?

Comment: ph number is not validating

Answer (score 1):

Here is example

```
 public class ValidatePhoneNumber {
 public static void main(String[] argv) {

  String sPhoneNumber = "605-8889999";
  //String sPhoneNumber = "605-88899991";
  //String sPhoneNumber = "605-888999A";

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}-\\d{7}");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sPhoneNumber);

  if (matcher.matches()) {
      System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form XXX-XXXXXXX");
  }
}
}
```

Also there is PhoneNumberUtils class in android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Comment: hi why ur taking sphonenumber in this code.directly u can use edittext name here

Comment: you can manage code in your style. you can make a function which take number params. i have just shown you a validation style and reg. you can change number format regex into your own type regix.

Comment: In My code if i enter characters also its taking in ph num even iam not getting phone number is invalid message can u please check my code

Answer (score 0):

```
/** isPhoneNumberValid: Validate phone number using Java reg ex. 
* This method checks if the input string is a valid phone number. 
* @param email String. Phone number to validate 
* @return boolean: true if phone number is valid, false otherwise. 
*/  
public static boolean isPhoneNumberValid(String phoneNumber){  
boolean isValid = false;  
/* Phone Number formats: (nnn)nnn-nnnn; nnnnnnnnnn; nnn-nnn-nnnn 
    ^\\(? : May start with an option "(" . 
    (\\d{3}): Followed by 3 digits. 
    \\)? : May have an optional ")"  
    [- ]? : May have an optional "-" after the first 3 digits or after optional ) character.  
    (\\d{3}) : Followed by 3 digits.  
     [- ]? : May have another optional "-" after numeric digits. 
     (\\d{4})$ : ends with four digits. 

         Examples: Matches following phone numbers: 
         (123)456-7890, 123-456-7890, 1234567890, (123)-456-7890 

*/  
//Initialize reg ex for phone number.   
String expression = "^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$";  
CharSequence inputStr = phoneNumber;  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);  
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);  
if(matcher.matches()){  
isValid = true;  
}  
return
```

isValid;
}